# Laravel Pass multiples parameters in url and take the specific parameter

Tags: laravel

Before I needed to pass 2 parameters per url to insert them, since they go in a staggered way, that is. First I create an Exam, then that exam has Questions. To do this, I decided to pass the id along the route

```
Route::resource('/exams/{exam}/questions');
```

For this I chose to pass it like this in the method I needed:

```
Route::get('/exams/{exam}/questions/{id}/edit', function ($examId, $questionId){})
    ->name('questions.edit');
```

Now, Question has Answers and to reference it, I create the resource path like this:

```
Route::resource('/exams/{exam}/questions/{question}/answers', 'Backend\AnswerController');
```

The problem is that, when I try to save an Answer, it generates 2 problems ...

- The first one, when I save the answer it throws me this error.

[image]

```
Illuminate\Routing\Exceptions\UrlGenerationException
Missing required parameters for [Route: answers.index] [URI: exams/{exam}/questions/{question}/answers].
```

- Second It does not matter in which of the questions you save it (if it has id 2, 3, 4 or N) the answer always takes as saved the question_id = 1;

Add my Controllers and routes

```
|        | GET|HEAD  | exams/{exam}/questions/{question}/answers                    | answers.index           | App\Http\Controllers\Backend\AnswerController@index                    | web        |
|        |           |                                                              |                         |                                                                        | auth       |
|        | POST      | exams/{exam}/questions/{question}/answers                    | answers.store           | App\Http\Controllers\Backend\AnswerController@store                    | web        |
|        |           |                                                              |                         |                                                                        | auth       |
|        | GET|HEAD  | exams/{exam}/questions/{question}/answers/create             | answers.create          | App\Http\Controllers\Backend\AnswerController@create                   | web        |
|        |           |                                                              |                         |                                                                        | auth       |
|        | GET|HEAD  | exams/{exam}/questions/{question}/answers/{answer}           | answers.show            | App\Http\Controllers\Backend\AnswerController@show                     | web        |
|        |           |                                                              |                         |                                                                        | auth       |
|        | PUT|PATCH | exams/{exam}/questions/{question}/answers/{answer}           | answers.update          | App\Http\Controllers\Backend\AnswerController@update                   | web        |
|        |           |                                                              |                         |                                                                        | auth       |
|        | DELETE    | exams/{exam}/questions/{question}/answers/{answer}           | answers.destroy         | App\Http\Controllers\Backend\AnswerController@destroy                  | web        |
|        |           |                                                              |                         |                                                                        | auth       |
|        | GET|HEAD  | exams/{exam}/questions/{question}/answers/{answer}/edit      | answers.edit            | App\Http\Controllers\Backend\AnswerController@edit                     | web        |
|        |           |                                                              |                         |                                                                        | auth       |
|        | GET|HEAD  | exams/{exam}/questions/{question}/answers/{id}/confirmDelete | answers.confirmDelete   | App\Http\Controllers\Backend\AnswerController@confirmDelete            | web        |
```

My Controller

```
public function index($examId, $questionId){
    $exams = Exam::findOrFail($examId);
    $questions = Question::findOrFail($questionId);
    $answers = Answer::all();


    return view('answer.index', compact('exams', 'questions','answers'));
  }

  public function create($examId, $questionId){
      $exams = Exam::find($examId);
      $questions = Question::find($questionId);

    /*.
      $isCorrect = Answer::where('is_correct', 1)->get();
      $isWrong = Answer::where('is_correct', 0)->get();
    */
      return view('answer.create', compact('exams', 'questions'));
  }

  public function store(AnswerStoreRequest $request, $questionId, Exam $exams){
      $answers = new Answer();
      $answers->description = $request->get('description');
      $answers->iframe = $request->get('iframe');
      $answers->image = $request->get('image');
      $answers->is_correct = $request->get('is_correct');
      $answers->question_id = $questionId;

      $answers->save();

      return redirect()->route('answers.index', $exams->id ,$answers->question_id);
  }
```

Any ideas or solutions to the problem I have?

**Edit 1**

Add Create answer view.

```
<form action="{{ route('answers.store', [$exams->id, $questions->id]) }}" method="POST">
```

change the `web.php`

```
Route::get('/exams/{exam}/questions/{question}/answers', ['as' => 'answers.index', 'uses' => 'Backend\AnswerController@index']);
Route::get('/exams/{exam}/questions/{question}/answers/create', ['as' => 'answers.create', 'uses' => 'Backend\AnswerController@create']);
Route::post('/exams/{exam}/questions/{question}/answers/', ['as' => 'answers.store', 'uses' => 'Backend\AnswerController@store']);

Route::get('exams/{exam}/questions/{question}/answers/{answer}/edit', ['as' => 'answers.edit', 'uses' => 'Backend\AnswerController@edit']);
Route::put('exams/{exam}/questions/{question}/answers/{answer}', ['as' => 'answers.update', 'uses' => 'Backend\AnswerController@update']);

Route::delete('exams/{exam}/questions/{question}/answers/{answer}', ['as' => 'answers.destroy' , 'uses' => 'Backend\AnswerController@destroy']);
Route::get('/exams/{exam}/questions/{question}/answers/{id}/confirmDelete',['as' => 'answers.confirmDelete', 'uses' => 'Backend\AnswerController@confirmDelete']);
```

and i also add the foreach of the index where I show the questions.

```
@foreach($questions->answers as $answer)
  <tr>
      <td>{{ $answer->id }}</td>
      <td>{{ $answer->description }}</td>
      <td>
          <a href="{{ route('answers.edit', [$exams->id, $questions->id, $answer->id]) }}"
             class="btn btn-warning btn-sm"><i class="far fa-edit"></i>
          </a>
          <a href="{{ route('answers.confirmDelete', [$exams->id, $questions->id, $answer->id]) }}"
             class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
          </a>
      </td>
  </tr>
  @endforeach
```

Comment: Can you please share the form you use to create the answer more specifically the url you're submitting the form to, maybe you're missing something there.

Comment: Done, I have added the form line

Comment: After saving/storing, in the store method, you are redirecting to answer.index routes with only 1 parameter that is answer. According to route it needs 'exam'id and 'question'id params. That explains the first error.

Comment: Yes, I already tried to add the data you needed. `public function store(AnswerStoreRequest $request, $questionId, Exam $exams)` and `return redirect()->route('answers.index', $exams->id, $answers->question_id);` but have the same problem.

Comment: i updated my store method.

Comment: Do you still get the Url Generation exception?

Comment: Also parameter order matters, it has to follow the same order as the route. That may explain the second problem. Route has exam then question, store method has question then exam..

Comment: @Avi I followed your advice and for the redirection I put it this way `return redirect()->route('answers.index', $exams->id, $questions->id);` but have same error.

Comment: Put exam id and question id in an array; just like you have in your form action, and see if it solves.

Comment: No, the error persists @Avi :(

Comment: you have to manually define a GET,POST,PUT,PATCH,DELETE methods in your routes check the updated answer

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the error, the whole page.

Comment: Yap, added the error image.

Comment: Thays not the entire page. I wanted to see the entire error bag.

Comment: The new image is a different error. It's for exam.index. We were tackling answers.index UrlGenerationException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing in multi parameters wrong when you are dealing with more than one parameter you need to specify which value belongs to which parameter.

So change

```
return redirect()->route('answers.index', $exams->id ,$answers->question_id);
```

To

```
return redirect()->route('answers.index', ['examId' => $exams->id ,'questionId' => $answers->question_id]);
```

see the [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#named-routes) for a accurate-ish explanation

**EDIT:** Also you are not passing a third required parameter it seems. i would suggest you manually define a GET,POST,PUT,PATCH,DELETE methods like so.

```
// Example
Route::get('example', ['as' => 'example.index', 'uses' => 'MyController@index']); // show all items
Route::get('example/create', ['as' => 'example.create', 'uses' => 'MyController@create']); // show the add new items
Route::post('example', ['as' => 'example.store', 'uses' => 'MyController@store']); // store new items
Route::get('example/edit/{id}', ['as' => 'example.edit', 'uses' => 'MyController@edit']); // edit existing items
Route::patch('example/update/{id}', ['as' => 'example.update', 'uses' => 'MyController@update']); // update existing items
Route::delete('example/delete/{id}', ['as' => 'example.delete', 'uses' => 'MyController@destroy']); // delete existing items
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but have the same error. Missing required parameters for [Route: answers.index] [URI: exams/{exam}/questions/{question}/answers]. ):

Comment: Oh thanks, I'm going to try it and tell you, now I'll be back.

Comment: i have the same error. No redirect and, insert on questions_id = 1

Comment: like i said, it should be named, please check my answer carefully

Comment: @EdgarGc you are missing the keys you need the keys ` ['examId' => $exams->id ,'questionId' => $answers->question_id] `

Comment: Yes, I already put it that way and it still generates the same error. `return redirect()->route('answers.index', ['examId' => $exams->id, 'questionId' =>  $answers->question_id]);`